# Random choice without repeats

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I need to generate a unique element each time random choice is run without any repeats each time its run (**lists are not allowed to be used** )
eg : `(x,y,z) (y,x,z) (z,y,x)`

```
from random import choice
operator=random.choice("xyz")
```

Comment: Before posting a question, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to include code in your question.

Comment: Are you looking for tuples if you do not want lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```py
import random

for i in range(5):
    print(random.sample("xyz", 3))

['y', 'z', 'x']
['z', 'y', 'x']
['z', 'x', 'y']
['x', 'y', 'z']
['z', 'x', 'y']
```

I think this is an equivalent solution:

```
for i in range(5):
    x = list("xyz")
    random.shuffle(x)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your example, you're trying to do permutations to find unique elements?

```
from itertools import permutations

for i in permutations("xyz"):
    print (i)

('x', 'y', 'z')
('x', 'z', 'y')
('y', 'x', 'z')
('y', 'z', 'x')
('z', 'x', 'y')
('z', 'y', 'x')
```